# include do css em outras páginas

Tags: php, css, include

Estou tentando colocar o *CSS* dentro de uma subpasta com o *include*, mas não consigo. Já usei `../`, `.../`, todos os tipos possíveis, mas não consigo.

a estrutura do meu projeto está assim:

- css[pasta]/css.css
- pages[pasta]/anuncios_user[pasta]/anuncios.php
- includes[pasta]/menu.php

Eu só consigo chamar o *CSS* pelo *include* até os arquivos que estão na pasta "Pages", mas quando chamo o *include* do menu, onde tem todos os *links* de *CSS* e afins, ele não vem.

Comment: Qual o código que você está usando? O `include` é do *PHP* ou do *CSS*?

Comment: é o include do php, nesse include tem a tag html ate o body

Answer (score 0):

Da algum erro?
quando inspeciona a pagina os links do css estão lá?
você disse: "é o include do php, nesse include tem a tag html ate o body"
vc está dividindo certo os includes para que o conteudo da pagina fique em body?

Outra coisa, pra você subir duas pastas tem que repetir ../../ e assim por diante.